# array.filter with async function not work

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await, next.js

Here's my code below.
I'm working on an array named `contentList` of length 8 that filters out all elements that do not work fine with `axios.get`.

It should have produced an array of length 5, but turns out to be length 8.
And `result` is empty just like all the `async await` things does not work.

What is wrong with my code? Any help would be appreciated.

```js
static async getInitialProps () {
  let result = {}

  const promises = contentList.filter(async ({hotList, newList, hotUrl, newUrl}) => {
    let hotRes, newRes
    try {
      hotRes = await axios.get(hotUrl)
      newRes = await axios.get(newUrl)
    } catch (e) {
      return false
    }

    // if (hotRes.data.code === 200) {
    result[hotList] = hotRes.data.data
    // }

    // if (newRes.data.code === 200) {
    result[newList] = newRes.data.data
    // }

    return true
  })

  const categoryList = await Promise.all(promises)

  console.log('categoryList', promises.length)

  return {
    categoryList,
    ...result,
  }
}
```

Comment: where did you get the idea from that inputting an asynch, promise returning function into `filter` which demands a function returning a boolean, was a good idea?

Comment: You cant use an `async` function as the parameter for filter. If you are trying to get it to run asynchronously, just put the filter into an async function

Comment: I saw [this solution](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/node-js-how-to-run-an-asynchronous-function-in-array-map) and performed exactly the same way, but got a wrong result